# overflow encountered in expm1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

the following code is from a reference notebook from Kaggle House Price Prediction:

```
X=train_df.drop(['SalePrice'],axis=1)
y=train_df.SalePrice

X_pwr=power_transformer.fit_transform(X)
test_std=std_scaler.fit_transform(test_df)
test_rbst=rbst_scaler.fit_transform(test_df)
test_pwr=power_transformer.fit_transform(test_df)

gb_reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=1792, 
learning_rate=0.01005, max_depth=4, max_features='sqrt', 
min_samples_leaf=15, min_samples_split=14, loss='huber', random_state =42)
gb_reg.fit(X_pwr, y)
y_head=gb_reg.predict(X_test)

test_pred_gb=gb_reg.predict(test_pwr)
test_pred_gb=pd.DataFrame(test_pred_gb,columns=['SalePrice'])
test_pred_gb.SalePrice =np.floor(np.expm1(test_pred_gb.SalePrice))

sample_sub.iloc[:,1]=(0.5 * test_pred_gb.iloc[:,0])+(0.5 * 
old_prediction.iloc[:,1])
#here old_prediction is the sample prediction given by kaggle
```

I wanna know the reason for the last line of code. Why they are assigning exponent of predicted values.
also, the last line is giving runtime warning: overflow encountered in expm1. I also wanna know how to solve this overflow problem because, after this step, all the SalePrice is replaced by Nan

Comment: for the first question because maybe somewhere before in your code they are doing np.sqrt

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, it is hard to say without seeing more code, though I doubt there is a good reason, as the numbers you are feeding `np.expm1` are apparently large (which makes sense if they're the sale prices of houses). This brings me to the second question:

`expm1` is a special function for computing `exp(x) - 1`. It returns greater precision for very small `x` than just using `exp(x) - 1`. I don't know the exact way in which numpy is performing the calculation, though typically it is done with a Taylor Series. You start with the Taylor Series for `exp(x)` and just move the initial term of 1 over to the other side to get `exp(x) - 1 =` a large polynomial sum of terms. This polynomial contains things like x^n and n! where n is the number of terms that the polynomial is taken to (i.e. the level of precision). For large `x`, the numbers get unwieldy pretty quick! In other words, you quickly approach the limits of how big a number can be represented in bits on your operating system. To show this, just try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import  warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error')

for i in range(200000):
    try:
        np.expm1(i)
    except Warning:
        print(i)
        break
```

Which, on my system, prints `710`. For a workaround, you may try and get away with making large numbers small (i.e. a price of $200,000 would really be 0.2 mega-dollars).

Comment: thanks a lot for answering the question. I have edited the question and written the whole code of model training. hope that now you'll be able to find the reason behind the expm1.Also the code that you've written gives 704 on my sys but i still don't understand how to make 200000 to 0.2m